# Angularjs locale in Controller

Tags: angularjs, localization, angular-controller

I am new to UI world and currently working on Localization. I was able to translate the texts which are in HTML files but came up in a situation where Controller returns a list of values which is being displayed in views looping through it. I am stuck how am I proceed to solve this:

Sample code:

part of view.html:

```
 <div ng-repeat="section in vm.sections" class="apiconfig-container">
            <div class="apiconfig-list-wrapper m-b-30">
                <div class="page-title-wrapper">
                    <h3>{{section.title}}</h3>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-list">
                    <tr ng-repeat="link in section.links">
                        <td><a href="{{link.href}}">{{link.name}}</a></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Part of Controller:

```
 this.sections.push(this.getLinks());

    getLinks() {
        const baseUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/config/#`;

        let array = [];

        if (!this.someCheck("some_condition")) {
            array.push({
                name: "test1",
                href: `${baseUrl}/test1`
            });

            array.push({
                name: "test2",
                href: `${baseUrl}/test2`
            });
        }

        return { title: "Configurations", links: array };
    }
```

This is just sample incomplete code. Basically, Controller is returning **name: "test1"** **name: "test2"** which I want to be a variable that should picked up from the locale file, how do I achieve that. Or is there any other better approach?

Comment: Are you using `angular-translate`?

Comment: yes. But, not sure how to do in this case